# CropImageActivity is not working in android

Tags: android, image, android-studio, imagepicker, image-cropper

This is my Manifest file i'm unable to use com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity
```

````
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ImagePicker">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
           <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
      android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: make sure you have added camera permissions.

Comment: Yes, I added camera permission. IDK why this dependency is not working with me